# gmock: How do I pass a pointer of a mock class into another class?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have to test the following classes with gmock and since I'm pretty new to Gmock Testing in general, I have no idea, where I'm getting these errors from. So I have my Model class in the Model.hpp, which looks like this:

```
class Model {
  public:
  Model(double delta_t) : Delta_t(delta_t){};
  void add_submodel(std::unique_ptr< Submodel > submodel_ptr); //function adds submodels to private vector below

  private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr< Submodel>> submodel;

  protected:
  const double Delta_t;
};
```

The class Model above is using the class Submodel, which is defined like this:

```
class Submodel {

  public:
  virtual ~ Submodel() {};
  virtual unsigned int get_number_of_states() = 0;
}
```

I have also defined the corresponding Mock Class for Submodel:

```
class MockSubmodel : public Submodel {

        public:
        MOCK_METHOD(unsigned int, get_number_of_states,(),(override));

    };
```

So far so good. Now, I want to test, whether the function model.add_subproblem(std::unique_ptr submodel_ptr) actually adds Submodels to the Model. So therefore I started to define the following test:

```
TEST(modelTest, Add_Submodel) {

    Model::Model model(1); 
  
    auto mock1_ptr = std::make_unique<Model::MockSubmodel>();
    model.add_subproblem(mock1_ptr);
    
}
```

The error I'm getting here is:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'unique_ptr<Model::MockSubmodel>' to 'unique_ptr<Model::Submodel>'
```

So my question: What is the right way to pass MockSubmodel as a pointer into add_submodel(), such that it can be recognised as a Submodel? I thought this would happen automatically because of gmock structure?

Comment: Did you try `add_subproblem(make_unique<...>(...))` or `add_subproblem(std::move(mock1_ptr))` ? Unique pointers are not copyable.

Comment: Yes, this helped me! I thought the problem was with gmock, so I did not consider that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add_submodel` function takes its `std::unique_ptr<Submodel>` parameter **by value**. When you call `model.add_subproblem(mock1_ptr);`, this would result in `mock1_ptr` being copied. However, unique_ptr is not copyable.

To fix this, you can remove the variable and directly pass the temporary, as in `model.add_subproblem(std::make_unique<Model::MockSubmodel>());`. Alternatively, you can **move** the unique_ptr in, as in `model.add_subproblem(std::move(mock1_ptr));` (but you must remember that mock1_ptr will become `nullptr` after this point).